# How do I change a user name in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I have an install of Windows 7 that I've already put a few days into. Today I realized I've made a mistake in the username and it's driving me nuts (my personal OCD).

While changing the physical folder name is perhaps possible, though quite involved, I do not want to open that can of worms.

What I want to do is simply change the username I give when the login prompt shows up. I thought it's possible by just renaming the user account in the User Accounts but that didn't work.

Is it possible to do then? Or is the only way to create another user and spend hour migrating everything I'd already customized to that user?

Comment: Renaming the account in the User Accounts control panel worked for me.

Comment: Snark, I just tried again and it didn't work. I wonder if it's related to having a Dell or the security utils that handle the fingerprint logins.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make a new account and do a settings and data transfer using [Windows Easy Transfer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer) from account to account! Delete the old account. All in all this will not take long depending on the size of your profile.

[image]

Comment: Your answer builds up on the other 2 by harrymc and Ivo but it's exactly what worked. I ended up doing Easy Transfer, picked the old user, then did the Easy Transfer again and told it that it's my new computer and then there was an option to remap the old user to a new one, including creating a brand new one. Of course some programs lost their settings because the path in their setting files was incorrect but that was expected. Dell's EMBASSY security center was the most pain actually - I had to reset all fingerprints using http://www.wave.com/support/documents/ESC/ESC-026.asp. THANK YOU ALL!

Comment: Dells software, I always (if buying dell) throw away emmediately. Just as I format all new laptops / pc's comming from Dell, HP, etc.

Comment: Sniek, likewise. It was a brand new install obviously, considering it's Windows 7. You have to use some software though, in order to use some features, like the fingerprint security.

Comment: Dell offers their software through their website. So just Format, install own OS en install software from Dell which you do need! ;)

Comment: Sniek, yes, that's exactly what I've done.

Answer (score 29):

Use the command `netplwiz`. It will give you a dialog box that will let you change the username instead of just the display name.

- Enter `netplwiz` at the command line
- Select the account and click the Properties button
- Enter the new name for the account

[image]

works perfect and quick you just need restart system after.

Comment: this works but of course it does not rename the underlying user folder, which is to be expected..

Answer (score 7):

Try the procedure described here : ["How to rename or move a User Profile folder ?"](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/userpath.htm).

**Renaming the user profile folder**

To rename (or move) the User Profile folder, you may use the following method. This method has been adopted from [KB314843](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314843/#XSLTH3129121125120121120120), but this page explains in detail how to rename an User account home directory.

Important note :
Though you can move or rename the user profile folder, there may be some side effects after using this method. This is because of the reason that there may be some absolute path references (to the old user profile folder) in the registry added by third-party software. Therefore, there may be a loss of functionality in the respective applications.

Before modifying the registry, you need to take a full backup, in case you want to Undo the changes or to recover from disasters caused by incorrect registry modifications if any. You may use [ERUNT](http://www.winxptutor.com/regback.htm) for a full registry backup. Use Registry Editor at your own risk.

Rename the User Profile folder using Windows Explorer:

- Logon to an admin account that is not the account being renamed.
- Open the Documents and Settings folder, by typing this in Start, Run dialog:
  `%systemdrive%\Documents and Settings`
  The list of folders will be displayed. Select the corresponding folder of the user account that you want to rename.

Example:

```
%SystemDrive%\Documents and Settings\OldUsername
becomes:
%SystemDrive%\Documents and Settings\NewUsername
```

Next step is to notify the system that the user profile path has changed.

**Changing the ProfileImagePath value in the registry**

The ProfileList registry key contains some sub-keys, which are nothing but the list of User Account Security Identifiers (SID). Each of the SID represents an Account. The key is located here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
```

Identify the SID for your User account, and change the Profile path

- To know the SID for your user account, you may use the script [sidlist.vbs](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/reg/SIDList.vbs)
- Download the script and run it.
  (The User Account names and SIDs will be listed in a log file, and opened automatically.)
- Note down the SID for your account.
- Then, in the Registry Editor, select the correct SID that belongs to your user account.
  In the right-pane, double-click the `ProfileImagePath` value and change the profile path. (ProfileImagePath stores the full path of the User account home folder. )

Example:

```
%SystemDrive%\Documents and Settings\OldUsername
becomes the following:
%SystemDrive%\Documents and Settings\NewUsername
```

Close Registry Editor, and restart Windows. See if you're able to logon to that user profile successfully. Additionally, to verify if the path has been changed successfully, type `SET` in the Command Prompt. In case you find any abnormal behavior when running an application, you may undo the above procedure.

Comment: Good link harry, I took the liberty to quote the page to make it easier

Comment: For some reason, when I make a new admin account, I still can't rename the old one. It even has a lock picture on it. I wonder if it's related to the Dell fingerprint software that handles the logins. I'll try turning that off.

Answer (score 1):

"What I want to do is simply change the username I give when the login prompt shows up. I thought it's possible by just renaming the user account in the User Accounts but that didn't work.

If it's just the name you see you want to change this is much easier:
Go to the user accounts and click on the account you want to change. Then Rename the username to the username you would like.
The user folders will still remain the old wrong username but at the login screen etc you'll see your new username.

Answer (score 1):

```
wmic useraccount where name='currentname' rename newname
```

Source: [Rename local user account](https://www.windows-commandline.com/rename-local-user-account/)

This would work for the editions having wmic.

Answer (score 0):

According to my own experiment, there're mainly 4 steps you have to do to change your account's login name safely as follows:

- Make full disk backup or create a disk restore point for disk C. This may be tedious but definitely necessary.
- Change your login name in various ways.

  - Running `netplwiz` as [user40662](https://superuser.com/users/40662/user40662) has pointed out.
  - Using `Computer Management` tool by running `compmgmt.msc`. Just modify your user settings under `Local Users and Groups`.
  - `wmic useraccount where name='currentname' rename newname` as [Sriniv](https://superuser.com/users/150120/sriniv) has pointed out although I didn't test it.
- Modify your user profile name and change the registry related. [harrymc's answer](https://superuser.com/a/47783/320453) is worth reading although not perfectly right due to the old `Documents and Settings`. Or you may refer to [How To Change A Windows Account Name And User Profile Folder Name - gHacks Tech News](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/03/28/how-to-change-a-windows-account-name-and-user-profile-folder-name/)

  - To rename your user profile, you have to create another temporary administrative account and login to it.
  - Rename your user profile `C:\Users\username` to `C:\Users\newusername`
  - Locate your own `ProfileImagePath` under the registry directory `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` and  change the value to your new profile directory name. Be careful not to change the wrong one.
  - Logout and relogin with your new account name and delete the temporary account.
- Post processing. It's predictable especially for some path settings.

  - You may have to selectively replace `C:\Users\username` with `C:\Users\newusername` in system registry if needed. Do a fully backup before massive modification!
  - For `cygwin` users like me, you need to run `mkpasswd -l > /etc/passwd;mkgroup -l > /etc/group` to refresh users and groups, then change the user directory name as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. Run the command `control userpasswords2` to open the User Accounts dialog
2. Select the user account to rename and click **Properties**
3. Enter the desired username in the *User name* field and click **OK**
4. Log out and back in if changing the account currently in use

**Note:** This does NOT rename the account's user profile folder.