# How do I change my Windows 7 User Account Name?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change a user name in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/47777/how-do-i-change-a-user-name-in-windows-7)

I have a Toshiba laptop with Windows 7 that I bought in 2010. I stupidly named my user accout sexygirl not knowing it would show up every time I sent a file. I am now a business management student and every time I attach a file it shows. For example: C:\Users\Sexygirl\Pictures\a\318002_10200140645389275_1388366052_n.jpg

How do I change this? I went to my control panel, then to Windows Credentials. It showed Internet or Network Address: Sexygirl but it gives me no option to edit. Is there another way? I am computer illiterate. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the following link where a similar question was raised:

[How do I change a user name in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/47777/how-do-i-change-a-user-name-in-windows-7)

Easiest way is to create a second account with the name that you want and transfer your settings to that new account.

Test everything under your new account. Disable your old account and once you are happy you have everything you had under your old account delete the old account.

Comment: If you find that the same question has been asked previously, mark the new one as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can changer your user account name without possibly corrupting your user profile is by creating a whole new user account, migrating your files over (or just using the new user for your "business management" stuff). You can create a new user by following the steps below:

1. Go to the control panel and go to "Users Accounts".
2. From there you will need to click "Manage another account".
3. Now you just need to click "Create a new account".

It is pretty strait forward from there. There is an option to change the account name immediately after the step where you click "User Accounts", but I have had bad luck with it corrupting the profile in multiple instances.

For more information on creating a new user account in Windows 7, please refer to [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Create-a-user-account) Microsoft web page. You would want the "workgroup" option.

For more informaiton on changing a user name in Windows 7, please refer to [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Rename-a-user-account) Microsoft web page. You would want the "workgroup" option. Again, I do not recommend this.