# Unable to change username

Tags: windows-7, credentials

I'm unable to change username in windows 7 home premium. Even if i change it in control panel, the old name appears in command prompt and also in c:\users. Is there any solution for this?
I tried lusrmgr.msc, it is showing,

> This computer is running Windows 7 Home Premium. This snapin may not be used with this version of Windows. To manage user accounts for this computer, use the user Accounts tool in the Control Panel.

Comment: see this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/47777/how-do-i-change-a-user-name-in-windows-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because `lusrmgr.msc` is a snap-in that is reserved for Windows 7 **Professional** version and beyond. It is not available in **Home Premium**.

Changing a username in the control panel doesn't change the actual system username or profile directory because there are certainly many applications that have been installed that are dependent upon that name and directory not changing.

Your only option is to create a new user and migrating the settings and files over with Windows Easy Transfer. As @[FrankThomas commented](https://superuser.com/questions/641473/unable-to-change-username#comment802697_641473), the process for doing this has been [asked before here](https://superuser.com/questions/47777/how-do-i-change-a-user-name-in-windows-7).

Comment: So without professional or above you have to do a super workaround way? Huh, doesn't seem like Microsoft.

Comment: Honestly, even if I did have Professional, I would still do it with Easy Transfer. Changing the profile directory without addressing the billion associated registry entries can cause half of installed applications to stop working.