# Windows username has been changed. But it hasn't. But it has

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, administrator

Windows 7 Pro 32 bits. I have changed the name of an account (that has admin rights) via control panel, and in the login screen it shows the new name. So far, so good.

However, when I start some software, it auto-fills the username field with the old account name, and errors when I fill it with the new name, saying the account does not exist.

Hm, weird. Upon further ispection, I find out that:

- The folder name in `c:\users` is still the name of the old account (but I suspect this is by design, to prevent malfunction of some poorly programmed software that might have it hardcoded somewhere)
- `net user` is still listing the old name
- When I clicking on a folder -> properties -> sharing -> advanced sharing -> checkbox "share folder" -> permissions -> add -> advanced -> objects -> checkbox "users" -> OK -> locate now (<del>uh, what was I even doing?</del>) lists the old account name.

Comment: You can't change the username of "Administrator" easily. Using Group Policy CAN but your software sounds very odd that it can't work if it doesn't get what it wants...

Comment: @Bob Yes, it is. Although, as you said yourself in the chatroom, the most voted and accepted answer is terrible. I ended up going with the `netplwiz` one.

Comment: @BigChris Ah, yes, a distinction should be made between renaming the builtin `Administrator` account (which should *never* be done - heck, there's basically never a good reason to *use* that account) and renaming *an* administrator account, i.e. a member of the `Administrators` group. The former has its own issues (again, should not be done), while the latter runs into the rename issues that apply to non-admin accounts too - namely, the User Accounts control panel won't change the actual user name, merely a display name.

Comment: So... what is exactly your problem?

Comment: Maybe you changed only Full Name? (which is basically... display name, not real login)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed only account name, which basically works as kind of "display name".

This is not login (`net user` shows login, not "account name"). <s>Login cannot be changed</s>.

You can create new account, transfer all data to it and remove old one,

or change it like this: [How do I change a user name in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/47777/how-do-i-change-a-user-name-in-windows-7/155239#155239)

Comment: Both account name and login name *can* be changed, I managed to do so by following the steps on the duplicate question

Comment: But duplicate question answer says "create new account", so this is not a change, it is new account.

Comment: @Kamil - The accepted answer says to make a new account, however [another answer](http://superuser.com/a/155239/128359) give steps on how to achieve this. Just because an answer is accepted does not automatically make it the only answer.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Thanks guys and sorry for wrong answer. I edited it so it's not wrong anymore.