# Renamed user account made a mess in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

In windows 7, I renamed the account name in `C:/users` and now after restarting the os, it recreate the desktop and remove everything it was in it. How can I fix the problem? I just want to have one user with all of my files in its folder.

I just saw that I had to follow this path: [How do I change a user name in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/47777/how-do-i-change-a-user-name-in-windows-7) but now it is too late :-(

Comment: After you renamed the user account and tried to log back in, it probably logged you in as TEMP user. Can you confirm if that's the case?

Comment: exactly, it is a TEMP user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following steps in order to get your user account back to the way it was before you mistakenly renamed it:

1. Go back to `C:\users` and rename the user profile folder back to what it originally was named.
2. Press `Windows Key + R` to bring up the Run window
3. Type in `regedit` and hit `Enter`
4. Navigate to the following location  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > Windows NT > Current Version > ProfileList`
5. Under ProfileList you will see a few subfolders with names like S-1-5-21-3463664321-2923530833-3546627382-1001  (just an example). Be sure to increase the width of the window so you can see all the way to the end of that long folder name.
6. Look for one folder in there that ends with `.bak`
7. First select that `.bak` folder and then right-click it and choose Rename.
8. Keep the entire name of that folder the same except remove just the .bak part of it at the end. So you want it to end with a number instead of a something like 2923530833.bak
9. Now log off and log back in as that original user account. It should be back to normal now.

Comment: I don't remember old username so how it can be fixed now?( actually someone else did this mess and I asked for him)

Comment: Follow the steps above navigating through the registry. When you find the folder with the .bak at the end of it, select it with your mouse and then look over at the window pane on the right. You'll see ProfileImagePath and then it lists C:\users\username , where *username* will be what it was originally named before.

Comment: good point! tnx

Comment: there is no entry in registery ending with .bak